# Does await inside a for loop block the main thread until the entire operation completes?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await

I am trying to assess whether `await` inside a `for` loop blocks the main thread until the entire operation is complete. It is unclear to me what occurs when await is inside a for loop:

```
for(const work of asyncWork) {
  await work;
}
```

Option 1:

```
  work1
  .then(work2)
  .then(work3)
  .then(work4)
  .then(work5)
```

Option 2:

```
  work1
  .then(continue);

  work2
  .then(continue);

  work3
  .then(continue);

  work4
  .then(continue);

  work5
  .then(continue);
```

Comment: Where you are using this `for-of`. You should use it inside `async`

Comment: Yes it is inside an async function

Comment: _"It is unclear to me what occurs when await is inside a for loop"_ - How about testing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is the correct answer. The `await` inside the `for` loop forms a promise chain. To demonstrate, you need to execute two `async` functions, both containing a `for` loop that iterates through an array of promises.
If you execute the code below, it logs out the two `for` loops concurrently:

Try running the snippet yourself:

```js
function work(log) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => { console.log(log); resolve(); }, 2000)
    });
}

let allWork = [() => work(1), () => work(2), () => work(3), () => work(4)];

async function doWork() {
    for (const workItem of allWork) {
        await workItem();
        console.log("After await workItem()");
    }
    console.log("After for");
}

doWork();
doWork();
console.log("After doWork");
```

You will see:

> After doWork
>
> 1
>
> After await workItem()
>
> 1
>
> After await workItem()
>
> 2
>
> After await workItem()
>
> 2
>
> After await workItem()
>
> 3
>
> After await workItem()
>
> 3
>
> After await workItem()
>
> 4
>
> After await workItem()
>
> After for
>
> 4
>
> After await workItem()
>
> After for

As you can see, the work is logged concurrently. The first `for` loop doesn't block the second from running to completion. `1` and `After await workItem()` get logged together because the javascript engine is smart enough to know that `console.log` doesn't need to be sent to the event loop. It can be inlined with the previous promise and executed synchronously.

There is no special magic happening here. Two javascript rules make this happen:

1. `await` does not block `for` or `while` loops from running to completion.
2. All `await` statements inside an `async` function are grouped together into a promise chain

Still unconvinced? The above code snippet behaves the same as the snippet below, which is a group of two promise chains:

```js
function work(log) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => { console.log(log); resolve(); }, 2000)
    });
}

work(1)
.then(() => console.log('After await workItem()'))
.then(() => work(2))
.then(() => console.log('After await workItem()'))
.then(() => work(3))
.then(() => console.log('After await workItem()'))
.then(() => work(4))
.then(() => console.log('After await workItem()'))
.then(() => console.log("After for"))

work(1)
.then(() => console.log('After await workItem()'))
.then(() => work(2))
.then(() => console.log('After await workItem()'))
.then(() => work(3))
.then(() => console.log('After await workItem()'))
.then(() => work(4))
.then(() => console.log('After await workItem()'))
.then(() => console.log("After for"))
 
console.log("After doWork")
```

One caveat to keep in mind is this behavior only applies with `for` and `while` loops when it comes to array iteration. Array iterators like `forEach` do not form promise chains the same way. That's because each step in `forEach` is an execution of a function. The JS engine will not group `awaits` inside a nested `async` function call into an ancestral `async` function call.

Comment: I misunderstood what you were asking.  Await obviously 'blocks' the async function it's in.  Your for loop doesn't exit until all the workitems have run, which wouldn't happen with a regular promise chain or even just taking async/await out.  I thought that was what you meant.  However await doesn't block the JavaScript thread completely.  In the end we're just setting up callbacks into the for loop that execute after the timeouts. So code outside of the async function can still run.  I was answering the wrong question, and have deleted the answer.  I'm glad you worked it out.

Comment: "Your for loop doesn't exit until all the workitems have run". Kind of-- "run" just means that it wraps the work in a promise. The loop doesn't stall to wait for the promise, which is what you had said in your answer. If you took await out, it wouldn't form a promise chain. It would execute a bunch of separate promises that resolve on their own. Await allows you to keep them in order (aka a promise chain).

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Yeah, everything *inside* the async function after the loop *is* blocked, in the sense that it's wrapped by `then`. My original question is about the main thread, which is not blocked by the `await` statement. `console.log('After for')` happens at the end because it's wrapped in `then`.